# XSLT extenison function call esacapes backslash

Tags: .net, xslt

When I call an extension c# function like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="extension:matches('\d', .)">
    <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
    <xsl:value-of select="blah"/></td>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="blub"/></td>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Then the functions receives as first argument "\\d".

I would like the function to just get a "\d" as first argument.

Why is this and what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was my own fault. The debugger shows a double backslash which is not there. I just accidentally switched the order of arguments of the function. Now it works without any escaping.